# Animated movie with dragons and a boy and girl from warring factions/kingdoms

Tags: story-identification, movie, dragons, animation

I had watched the movie when I was younger and have no memory of its title. It is an animated movie that couldn't have come out after 2013. The animation was also super choppy compared to things like Disney at the time.

The two main characters are a boy and a girl from warring factions/kingdoms. They meet after finding a crashed dragon and get this weird marking on their faces. The villain is secretly a dragon disguised as a human that has been manipulating both kingdoms.

Comment: Was the animation hand-drawn or computer-generated?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest_for_Camelot?

Answer (score 12):

This is very likely **[Dragons: Fire and Ice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons:_Fire_and_Ice)**.

It's a direct-to-DVD computer-animated film from 2004 based on the Mega Bloks toyline, and aired on the Jetix children's television network in 2005.

- The film features a boy, prince Dev from the Norvagen kingdom, and a girl, princess Kyra, from the Draigar kingdom.
- These kingdoms blame each other for the disappearance of dragons.
- A black dragon falls through a portal, and "marks both the children with his mystical teardrops":

  [image] [image]
- The antagonist is Xenoz, an ice wizard, but "*gifted with great power by the Dragon King Thoron*" ([source](https://dragonsuniverse.fandom.com/wiki/Xenoz)):

  [image]

Answer (score 7):

Is this ***[Dragons: Fire & Ice](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0425960/?ref_=kw_li_tt)*** (2004)...?

> Two young rival dragon riding warriors fight to end a 1000 year old war despite the hidden manipulator opposing them.

The story is set in a fantasy world with two warring kingdoms: the Norvagens and Draigar. The protagonists are Prince Dev of the former and Princess Kyra of the latter. In the early scenes, they're both preteens, but there's a timeskip of eight years, after which they're both teenagers.

Around seven minutes into the film, Dev and Kyra are both riding dragons when another dragon falls from a portal in the sky, knocking them to the ground as well. While they're unconscious, the dragon that fell from the sky marks both of their faces with teardrops and then disappears.

There is a villain who was secretly manipulating the two kingdoms into warring with one another, but while he wore a mask (that looked like a normal face) to conceal burns on his face that most people didn't know about, he wasn't a dragon in disguise. He did however have a secret alliance with an evil dragon.

I could say more, but I'd be spoiling things that weren't mentioned in your question.